# No admin data found

Tags: debugging, caching, facebook-insights

I tried to claim "Insight for my website" and i get the error "No admin data found at root webpage http://akcja-nikon.pl/. Insights requires admin data at this root webpage for the specified URL akcja-nikon.pl"

Admin tag data is there, i triple checked it, on both index.php and pickup.php (index redirects to pickup - in case you ask). I've done it almost a hundred times on all my other domains and never had a problem with that. I started having issues last week on this and one more domains.

Debugger scraps weird content for the URL an breaks after the first line on the HTML code

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=akcja-nikon.pl%2Fpickup.php

and flags the error in red "Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL."

Any ideas? Maybe some weird Facebook cache?

Comment: Did you click the "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" link at the bottom of the page?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

Comment: and the html code is standard html5 tag "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"

Answer (score -2):

> Admin tag data is there, i triple checked it, on both index.php and pickup.php (index redirects to pickup - in case you ask).

No, it does not.

Your `index.php` redirects to `agegate.php` via JavaScript – which the Facebook scraper doesn’t care about.

And calling `agegate.php` directly, without any cookies set (which the scraper does not care for either), delivers a just an error message,

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
result resource in <b>/home/marketingpic/include-pl.php</b> on line <b>38</b>
```

together with an HTTP status code `302 Moved Temporarily` and a **faulty** Location header that just says `Location: pickup.php`. (Faulty, because a *fully qualified* URL is **required** as value for a Location header by definition.)

And if I call your `pickup.php`, again without any cookies, it tries to send me back to `index.php` again (and again with a faulty Location header).

---

No idea, what exactly you are trying to accomplish here – but the *way* you are doing it right now, seems to be quite a nonsense.